# Swift1.2 let realm = Realm() でSIGABRTになる

Tags: swift, realm

はじめまして。
私は個人でSwiftによるiOSアプリ開発を勉強中です。

GoogleMapのSDKを使用して、ある地点からの動いた距離をカウントし
履歴に保存する機能を実装中なのですが、
その履歴データの保存にRealmを使おうと思い試行錯誤しています。

アプリ内で以下のコードの部分でSIGABRTが出力され終了してしまいます。

間違っている部分をご教示ください。

```
inport UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import Spring
import RealmSwift

class Record: Object {
    dynamic var distance = Double()
    dynamic var average = Double()
    dynamic var createdDate = Double()
}

class GMapViewController: BaseViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    //     中略
    @IBAction override func onClickSpButton(sender: SpringButton) {
        // ボタンが押されたらデータを保存
        let myRecord = Record()
        myRecord.distance = sumDistance
        myRecord.average = 0.0
        myRecord.createdDate = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        let realm = Realm()    // ここでエラー
        realm.beginWrite()
        realm.add(myRecord)
        realm.commitWrite()
    }
}
```

Comment: エラーになる部分を表すコメント箇所が誤っていたため修正しました。失礼しました。

Answer (score 2):

このコードに特に問題はありません。
Realmの初期化でエラーになるということですので、セットアップが間違っているのではないでしょうか？

どのようにRealmをセットアップしましたか？

もし、Webサイトからダウンロードしたフレームワークを使っているなら、下記のEmbedded Binariesに設定されているかどうか確認してください。

Dynamic Frameworkは動的にリンクされるので、アプリケーションに含まれている必要があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: インストールはCocoaPodsを使用しました。
セットアップが正しく行われていない可能性があるとのことで、
念のためプロジェクトを新規作成後CocoaPodsからRealmをインストールし、
そのプロジェクトに同一のソースをコピーして実行したところ問題なく動作しました。